# How to read specific amounts of code in a SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to read a part of a SimpleXMLElement/XML file.
The problem is I can't get the desired text anyway I try.

I tried debugging the XML I had, so I printed it this way:

```
 foreach($response->items as $item) {
                   fwrite($file, var_export($item, TRUE));
               }
```

which outputs

> SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
>      'item' => 
>     array (
>       0 => 
>       SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
>          'id' => '000-1',
>          'description' => 'Notebook Prata',
>          'quantity' => '1',
>          'amount' => '1830.00',
>       )),
>       1 => 
>       SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
>          'id' => 'AB01',
>          'description' => 'Notebook Preto',
>          'quantity' => '2',
>          'amount' => '1340.00',
>       )),
>     ),
>   ))

But when I try to retrieve the data inside the specific items, the return is empty.
I tried the following:

```
fwrite($file, $item->amount);
//
fwrite($file, $item->{'amount'});
//
fwrite($file, $items->$item->amount);
```

But nothing seems to work.

How can I correct the syntax, to obtain the expected? I would want the file to have written '1830.00' and '1340.00', but I only get blanks.

[XML LIKE THIS FOR REFERENCE](http://pastebin.com/bASUiMFE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have been fooled by the fact that this seems logical if you read it in English:

```
foreach($response->items as $item) {
```

But it doesn't match the structure of the XML.

Consider this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><a>
    <b>
        <c>first C</c>
        <c>second C</c>
    </b>
</a>
```

If `$response` is the whole document (`<a>...</a>`), then to access each `<c>`, you need to do this:

```
foreach($response->b->c as $c)
```

Your XML has this same structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><transaction>
    ...
    <items>
        <item>first item</item>
        <item>second item</item>
    </items>
    ...
</transaction>
```

So your loop needs to be:

```
foreach($response->items->item as $item)
```

Then the children of `<item>` will be available as you expected, such as the `<amount>`:

```
echo $item->amount;
```